# Using Embedded Fonts for ComboBox and TextBox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, fonts

This question helped me learn how to embed fonts in my VB 2010 application -> [How to embed fonts for Use in a Visual Basic Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589932/how-to-embed-fonts-for-use-in-a-visual-basic-project)

There is no UseCompatibleTextRendering property, however, for a ComboBox or a TextBox.

Is it possible to use an embedded font for a ComboBox or a TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

While I was not able to use Fonts embedded as resources for a ComboBox and a TextBox, I was able to use fonts installed in the same directory as my application.

When I added the fonts (installed in the directory of my application by the installer) using this code, the UseCompatibleTextRendering property did not seem to matter:

```
    If _pfc Is Nothing Then
        _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection
    End If

    For Each fontfile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(filepath & "\Fonts", "*.ttf")
        _pfc.AddFontFile(fontfile)
    Next fontfile
```

Comment: I can confirm this is true (using C#).  Have you been able to find a way to make it work with TextBox, RichTextBox, Combobox, Listbox, etc yet ?  I have a difficult time believing the only way to use a custom font is to distribute the file (which could break certain font license agreements)

Comment: Sadly, I haven't.  In my case I was allowed to distribute the fonts, but I can understand how that wouldn't always be the case.  I tried the other solutions in this question but couldn't get them to work -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042199/embed-custom-font-fot-text-box-use-in-visual-basic-2010

Comment: I figured out a solution that works, and will be posting it as an answer to my other question here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115880/how-to-render-a-font-from-privatefontcollection-memory-to-editable-controls

Comment: Here is the working solution to this problem (in C# but easily converted to Visual Basic if you require) .  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33171089/3504007